# Incorrect ray intersections when face vertices are not located at z=0

Tags: three.js

I have created a plane surface (THREE.js, CanvasRenderer) which is made up of multiple triangular faces. I want the faces to change their color randomly when I hover the mouse pointer over them. When all the vertices of the faces are at z = 0, it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/koweiny/FT4uS/

But when I set the faces to any other value, let's say z = -10, it behaves in a crazy way, as if the surface were now a reflection of an invisible surface at z = 0:

http://jsfiddle.net/koweiny/FT4uS/2/

The only change in the code is the 3rd component of the variable node, which is -10 now for all the vertices:

```
var node = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, -10);
```

instead of

```
var node = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ray.intersectObjects()` requires face centroids.

```
geometry.computeCentroids();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FT4uS/5/

three.js r.53

Comment: Not anymore with r54 though :)

Answer (score 0):

This reminded me of some strange behavor with intersectObjects.
My guess was if you had a object far away from the center of scene, the boudingSphere was huge, so something when i moved my mouse over an empty space next to it, this function returned me still the object next.

So to prevent that i made this function to be sure, it just compare the Point in the object with boundingBox.

```
_this.checkIfPointMatchBox = function( set ) {      
    if (set.point.x < set.object.geometry.boundingBox.min.x || set.point.x > set.object.geometry.boundingBox.max.x) {
        return false;
    }
    if (set.point.y < set.object.geometry.boundingBox.min.y || set.point.y > set.object.geometry.boundingBox.max.y) {
        return false;
    }
    if (set.point.z < set.object.geometry.boundingBox.min.z || set.point.z > set.object.geometry.boundingBox.max.z) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```